# Find the largest number and smallest number such that the following bound is true

Tags: calculus

I am not sure how to start this question:

A function $f$ is known to satisfy $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Moreover, it is known that $-2 \leq f'(x) \leq 3$ for $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$. Find the largest number and smallest number such that the following bound is true:

$$ \rule{1cm}{0.15mm} \leq f(\frac{1}{2}) \leq \rule{1cm}{0.15mm} $$

Note: In other words, the numbers on the left-side and right-side should be the endpoints of the smallest interval of all possible values for $f(\frac{1}{2})$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a function whose codomain are real numbers, what do these inequalities mean?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, the original question did not have $(x_{1}, y_{1})$ and $(x_{2}, y_{2})$. I added them to make sense. The original question just had blanks

Answer (score 1):

Draw a straight line through $(0,0)$ with maximum derivative $3$, and you find that $f(1/2) = 3/2$. Draw a straight line through $(0,0)$ with minimum derivative $-2$, and you find $f(1/2) = -1$.

Now do the same starting with the point $(1,1)$ and you find a maximum value of $f(1/2) = 2$ and a minimum value of $f(1/2) = -1/2$.

Combine these results and you see that $-1/2 \le f(1/2) \le 3/2$.

Comment: Great. Thank for that explanation.